# SQL query with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clarification needed

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to use the following query:

```
   INSERT INTO table1(col1, col2, col3)
   SELECT ss.col1, ss.col2, ss.col3
   FROM table2 ss
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   col1=ss.col1,
   col2=ss.col2,
   col3=ss.col3;
```

Unfortunately all I get is "SQL query not properly ended" message. 
Where in this example the syntax is wrong?

The error message pops up right when I insert

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
       col1=ss.col1,
       col2=ss.col2,
       col3=ss.col3;
```

Comment: This synthax doesn't exist? :)

Comment: I found this query on stackoverflow, it should be correct, but it does not work for me. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: "on duplicate key update" only works for MySql, oracle DB requires the use of the merge keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle doesn't support the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax.  That appears to be MySQL-specific syntax.

Most likely, you would appear to want a `MERGE` statement

```
MERGE INTO table1 t1
  USING (SELECT col1, col2, col3 
           FROM table2) ss
     ON (t1.col1 = ss.col1) -- whatever the key is
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET t1.col1 = ss.col1,
                t1.col2 = ss.col2,
                t1.col3 = ss.col3
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
     INSERT( t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3 )
       VALUES( ss.col1, ss.col2, ss.col3 )
```